# How to get created time for package in nexus through api

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I use nexus to store my java artifacts using for my projects. Now I want to find any packages which is create after specific date. I followed nexus api document: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api. But it doesn't help for this case. Any suggestion for me?
(Nexus version: OSS 3.16.2)